# Using Quicktime C API framework on 64bits

Tags: avfoundation, quicktime, qtkit

I've searched on net for this but couldn't find much. Can I use QuickTime C api on 64 bits windows?
I know it works on 32 bits but it is possible to use it on 64bits.
I'm looking for encoding between different file formats. 
On Apple developer site I found reference of QTKit and AVFoundation. Is it possible to use these two with Visual C+?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.  QTKit and AVFoundation are Mac specific, and as far as I know Apple has never made a 64 bit version of the QuickTime C API for Windows.  Some apps get around it by using 32 bit "helper" apps which feed data into the 64 bit application.